# What and why is the result by running tmp()?

Tags: python-3.x, properties, decorator

I think tmp() is the same with f2(). But I get 2 different results.

```
def w1(func):
    def inner():
        print("Verifying ......")
        return func()
    return inner

@w1
def f2():
   print('f2')

f2()
print("Equivalently:") 
tmp = w1(f2)
tmp()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer of `tmp()` and `f()` are different because when we assign `tmp=w1(f2)` `tmp` now points to the `inner()` inner function. Remember that you return `inner` as a function when you call `w1(f2)` due to this `"Verifying ......"` is executed. And when you call `tmp()` it again execute `inner()` with `f2()`. So that's the reason why `tmp()` and `f()` are different.